# In Excel in value_if_true field i have a concatenate formula. It works fine for first cell but messes up when i drag it to other cells

Tags: arrays, if-statement, excel-formula, advanced-custom-fields, complextype

Task is to merge/concatenate two columns with "on" between columns and display it next corresponding column depending on the Department_code.

[image]

As in example i have to combine Department and Location from table 6 and place results in Department_Location of table 5.

Formula which i am pasting in cell is

> =IF(F9="A",(J9&" on "&K9), IF(F9="ER",(J10& " on "&K10), IF(F9="HR", (J11&" on "&K11), IF(F9="IT", (J12 & " on " & K12), IF(F9="LD",(J13 &"
>   on "&K13), IF(F9="M",(J14 & " on " &K14), IF(F9="MC", (J15&" on
>   "&K15), IF(F9="PG",(J16 & " on "&K16), IF(F9="RD",(J17& " on "&
>   K17))))))))))

[image]

It works fine for first value but when i drag it to other cells it gives weird results. The formula changes to

> =IF(F10="A",(J10&" on "&K10), IF(F10="ER",(J11& " on "&K11), IF(F10="HR", (J12&" on "&K12), IF(F10="IT", (J13 & " on " & K13),
>   IF(F10="LD",(J14 &" on "&K14), IF(F10="M",(J15 & " on " &K15),
>   IF(F10="MC", (J16&" on "&K16), IF(F10="PG",(J17 & " on "&K17),
>   IF(F10="RD",(J18& " on "& K18))))))))))

which is wrong

What i was expecting was this:

> =IF(F10="A",(J9&" on "&K9), IF(F10="ER",(J10&" on "&K10),
>   IF(F10="HR", (J11& " on "&K11), IF(F10="IT", (J12&" on "&K12),
>   IF(F10="LD",(J13 & " on " & K13), IF(F10="M",(J14 &" on "&K14),
>   IF(F10="MC", (J15 & " on " &K15), IF(F10="PG",(J16&" on "&K16),
>   IF(F10="RD",(J17 & " on "&K17))))))))))

Comment: You've left all your cell references as relative which means they update as you drag the formula around.  If you want `J9` to always look at `J9` you need to write it as `$J$9`.  I would point to documentation on this site, but it hasn't been written as far as I can tell, so here's a link to the MS Documentation:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9

Comment: Additionally, you could save yourself writing long `IF` functions if you used a `VLOOKUP` function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `$` in front of your cell references if you don't want them to adjust when you drag. Instead of `=IF(F10="A",(J9...` use `=IF(F10="A",(J$9...`.

Try using `VLOOKUP` to make your life simpler:
`=VLOOKUP(F9,I$9:K$17,2)&" on "&VLOOKUP(F9,I$9:K$11,3)`

[image]

[Documentation on VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)